# Grep / Regex pattern for HTML tag containing certain keyword

Tags: html, regex, grep

I'm having trouble with selecting everything between and including `<p` and `/p>` that contains `www.test.com` using grep find in BBEdit.

Sample HTML Code

```
<p>....</p><p align="center"><a href="http://www.test.com" title=""><img src="http://www.test.com/test.jpg"></a></p>
```

Desired result

```
<p align="center"><a href="http://www.test.com" title=""><img src="http://www.test.com/test.jpg"></a></p>
```

I've tried the below grep pattern....

```
<p.+?www\.test\.com.+?/p>
```

The Lookforward portion of the pattern `.+?/p>` works well, the problem is the Lookback pattern `<p.+?`, result is often too greedy, essentially selecting too many prior `<p` up to and including the one with keyword. I'm only after the first `<p`.

Essentially I want to remove these code from a large HTML file (50mb), the ideal solution would be a BBEdit grep find pattern that works as this is what I'm familiar with, however if there is a better way to do the same then I'm all ears.

Comment: You can't parse html with regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175615

Comment: I realise it's not ideal, but all I've got to do are these few lines then re-upload the file so thought I could do it using a text editor like BBEdit, find and replace with a grep pattern. Is there a simple tool I could use to do the same without a big learning curve?

Comment: Go get a html parser, for real. regex is going to let you down every time when parsing HTML or XML.